# Chrome breaking vertical alignment on printed tables

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

This is a difficult one to explain. A picture speaks a thousand words, so here we go:

[image: Screenshot of print preview]

Note the issue on the fourth line - the content of those four cells has been pushed *outside* the cell.

The HTML is very standard. A whole bunch of `<tr>` tags, each with 5 `<td>` tags. There's no particularly odd CSS:

```
table {border-spacing:0; width:100%; border-collapse:collapse} 
td {padding:3px; vertical-align:top; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; background:#fafafa}
```

One thing to note is the grey border is on the `<td>`, not the `<tr>` - this border appears in the correct space, so it's just the content of the table cell that is pushed down.

I have commented out all the CSS, the issue still happens.

In the 5 page printout this issue only occurs once, however there are another couple of issues in it:

- Two rows are roughly 1.5 times the height they should be. One has the whitespace above the text, the other below
- When I commented out the CSS, I noticed that some rows were split right down the middle (even when I had `tr, td {page-break-inside:avoid}` in my CSS
- In my testing, I discovered that the source code displayed in Chrome was different to the HTML delivered (as caught on an HTTP sniffer). Specifically it was missing a single `</` mid-way through (from a `</a>`), making the HTML invalid. Pretty sure this is a red herring.

In order to test this, I've made a copy of the page, removed sensitive data, trimmed off all the excess fat, and the issue is definitely still present. This can be viewed at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8750708/test.html .

Open that link in Chrome, go to the print preview (Ctrl-P) and you'll *hopefully* see the issues. I'm not sure if it'll be 100% consistent from machine-to-machine for me, but I see issues at:

- 3/4 of the way down page 1, W00629
- Bottom of page 1, chopped off
- 1/2 way down page 2, W00592
- Bottom of page 2, chopped off
- 1/3 way down page 3, W00607
- Near top of page 4, W00561/W00512
- Bottom of page 4, chopped off

In terms of further testing I have swapped the order of the rows. The problem occurs in the same place, so I believe it is NOT related to the contents of the cells.

So, any magic trick I'm missing in my CSS? Is this a bug in Chrome?

edit: Only confirmed in Chrome on Windows - obviously other OS'es may be different due to different font handling.

Comment: This appears fine in firefox.. are you using a script to generate this table?

Comment: Yes I'm using a script to generate it, but it doesn't matter - see the link before to http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8750708/test.html which is static HTML and the issue is still there. And I know it appears fine in Firefox. As you might notice from the title mentioning "Chrome", the four times I mentioned "Chrome" in the body, or the "google-chrome" tag, it is an issue in Chrome. Seems to work fine in every other browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try this dark magic javascript workaround. Also set border-spacing:0 on the table and be sure to remove top/bottom margins on elements above the table. You can replace them with padding. Details on [how this works](http://somacss.com/examples/print/bugs/chrome/tables.html) and an [example](http://somacss.com/examples/print/bugs/chrome/tables_fix.html).

```
var tableClass = 'chromePrint';
function ischrome() { return Boolean(window.chrome); }

if ( ischrome() ){
    if (document.styleSheets.length == 0){
        var st = document.createElement('style');
        st.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(st);
    }
    function fixChromeTablePrinting(){
        var ss = document.styleSheets[0];
        var dt = document.getElementsByClassName(tableClass);
        for(var t=0;t<dt.length;t++){
            var rows = dt[t].getElementsByTagName('tr');
            var lastRow = rows[rows.length-1];
            var cells = lastRow.getElementsByTagName('td');
            var tableWidth = 0;
            var mediaPrintRules = '.'+tableClass+' tr { display: table }';
            mediaPrintRules += '.'+tableClass+' tr { width: 100% }';
            //set sane (relative to chrome bugs) defaults in case someone forgot
            mediaPrintRules += 'body { margin: 0}';
            mediaPrintRules += '.'+tableClass+' { border-spacing: 0 }';
            for (var i=0;i<cells.length;i++){ tableWidth += cells[i].clientWidth; }
            for (var i=0;i<cells.length;i++){
                var per = (100 * (cells[i].clientWidth / tableWidth)).toFixed(2);
                mediaPrintRules += '.'+tableClass+' td:nth-child('+(i+1)+') {width: '+per+'%}';
            }
            ss.addRule('@media print', mediaPrintRules);
        }
    }
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fixChromeTablePrinting, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Five years later I'm still having the same problem with `vertical-align`, but it *does* seem to respect flex box placement - this prints correctly, with "hey" at the bottom.

```
<html>                       
<head>     
<style>
.down {                                                                    
  display: flex;           
  justify-content: flex-end;                                                                
  flex-direction: column;                                                                   
  height: 300px;                                                                            
  background: #ccf;                                                                         
}                                                                                           
.down > div {                                                                               
  background #cfc;                                                                          
}                                                                                           
</style>                                                                                    
</head>                                                                                     
<body>                                                                                      
<div class="down">                                                                          
  <div>hey</div>                                                                            
</div>                                                                                      
</body>                                                                                     
</html>
```